# Adding a query parameter that shows when a user visits the page

Tags: javascript, query-string

I wonder if it is possible to add a query parameter that is automatically added when a user visits the page? For example `https://example.org/example-script.js` becomes `https://example.org/example-script.js?example=value`. Does anyone know a way to do this? If yes, please answer to this. I am thankful to every useful answer I get.

Answer (score 0):

A js file won't execute in the browser if navigated directly to. You'd need to hit a regular document (like a .html) to do it, and then execute the javascript file from there.

That being said, what you want to do is basically this:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

urlParams.set('example', 'value');

window.location.search = urlParams;
```

This will not reload the page, and simply add your query params like you wanted to.

Comment: Nono, this is not what i meant. I dont wanna execute a js file in the browser, im asking how can i do it, that it adds the variables i want in there? For example: The user visits `example-jsfile.js` but then the js adds the parameters `example-jsfile.js?example=value`. I hope this is more accurate info for you, to understand what i mean.

Comment: Okay I dont quite get it. i made a js to test it out,  but it literally doesnt add the variable. Is that only for HTML <script> or for the JS File directly?

Comment: nvm it is. But now i have another issue, the page wont stop reloading constantly, anyway to fix this?

Comment: Seems like i only had to remove the `window.location.search = urlParams;` in the script and it fixed the issue, still does it is an issue if i remove this? Or can i simply let it out of the code?

Comment: Alright it seems it doesnt. I added it back, now it wont stop reloading. Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I am questioning your reasoning, and before an actual answer can be useful you have to show more of the surrounding code.

So let me first give feedback on the question itself: if you wish to keep track if a user has visited a page already it is much more useful to store that in a cookie, or something like localstorage. However take note that actually doing this is iffy in the privacy department in lots of parts of the world.

In the idea you propose you actively change the url - so you would trick the browser to go to another page (or at least bookmark tools would bookmark another page).

Now the second problem, what do you mean by "visit a page" - your example shows a link to a javascript source. Something that is not typically a "page"...

But considering you truly return an HTML page on that site, and you really want to store this inside the URL you would use some `onload` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) even together with `window.pushState` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>onload test</title>
    // ES5
    <script>
        function load() {
            window.history.pushState({example: value}, '');
        }
        window.onload = load;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>The load event fires when the document has finished loading!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you dont quite understand it. What i wanna say with this is when a user visits the page the `example.js` gets replaced with `example.js?example=value` this is what i mean with that.

Comment: @rhong59 so improve the question :)

Comment: @rhong59 you mean that instead of *loading* the resources from `.../example.js` you load the resource from `.../example.js?example=value` ? Then it depends on how you load the resource in the first place, is it automated, on clicking a link an ajax call?

Comment: no that is not really what I mean. What i wanna know is, if it is possible, that if you view a JS directly, that it automatically adds parameters. `example.js` -> `example.js?example=value`